# SQL - How to write CASE WHEN if dates in same group are different?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, case, window-functions

I want a column to get attention to rows that don't have matching dates for its group.
So when State and city are the same but date is different, display 'Date Mismatch'.

**Data:**

| State | City | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Texas | Austin | 2023 |
| Texas | Austin | 2023 |
| Texas | Austin | 2020 |
| Texas | Houston | 2023 |
| Texas | Houston | 2023 |

My example code:

```
SELECT
    State,
    City,
    Date,
    CASE
        WHEN --Logic here -- 
    THEN 'Date Mismatch'
    ELSE NULL
    END
FROM
    Table
WHERE 
    State IN (SELECT state FROM table GROUP BY state, city, date)
    AND
    City IN (SELECT city FROM table GROUP BY state, city, date)
```

**Expected results:**

| State | City | Date | Checks Column |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Texas | Austin | 2023 | Date Mismatch |
| Texas | Austin | 2023 | Date Mismatch |
| Texas | Austin | 2020 | Date Mismatch |
| Texas | Houston | 2023 |  |
| Texas | Houston | 2023 |  |

Comment: why is this tagged with SQL Server *and* MySQL? They're different databases.

Comment: your formatting is incomprehensible.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Date is mismatched according to what?

Comment: Also, your query is using correlated-subqueries - that's generally a bad thing - and your `WHERE` predicates look like they'll always succeed.

Comment: Texas-houston-2023 (no mismatch), but texas-austin-2023 (there is mismatch?) but again, for Texas-Austin-2020 (mismatch)? too confusing

Comment: Check out https://dbfiddle.uk/T4vCHqEJ to see if that helps - that's a MySQL query. https://dbfiddle.uk/5scbJ5o7 is for SQL Server.

Answer (score 2):

You can use window functions for this. Simply compare `MIN` with `MAX`

```sql
SELECT *,
  Checks =
    CASE WHEN MIN(Date) OVER (PARTITION BY State, City)
           <> MAX(Date) OVER (PARTITION BY State, City)
         THEN 'Date Mismatch' END
FROM YourTable t;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/dqeNdzBi)

Answer (score 0):

You can use WINDOW FUNCTION(DENSE_RANK) For find  DistincCount date

then check DistincCount for  Checks Column date

```
    
;with _City_State as (

    select state
        ,city
        ,dates 
       , DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY state,city ORDER BY dates ASC) +
         DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY state,city ORDER BY dates DESC) - 1 AS DistincCount
    from City_State

)

select 
        state
        ,city
        ,dates as date
        ,case when DistincCount=1 then '' else 'Date Mismatch' end  as [Checks Column]
from _City_State
```

You can insert Base data  with the following statements:

```
 drop table if exists City_State

create table City_State (state nvarchar(100), city nvarchar(100), dates varchar(4));

insert into City_State values ('Texas', 'Austin', '2023')
insert into City_State values ('Texas', 'Austin', '2023')
insert into City_State values ('Texas', 'Austin', '2020')
insert into City_State values('Texas', 'Houston', '2023')
insert into City_State values('Texas', 'Houston', '2023')
```